# Exception Handling in underflow while doing POP in Stack

Tags: c++, algorithm, stack

I want to know how to apply **exception handling** when the **top** variable reaches to a value **-1** (no element left to pop). Currently, I am using **cout** to nofity the user about the **stack underflow** and returning **0**, which is not a good practice. What improvement overall can be made to this **pop** function and how to notify user and handle the exception when stack reaches a state of underflow.

```
int Mystack::pop()
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        std::cout << "Stack Underflow" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    { 
        std::cout << "The popped element is" << A[top];
        return A[top--];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The Main Section :

```
case 4:
            std::cout << "POP the element" << std::endl;
            s1.pop();
            break;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can throw an `out_of_range` exception:

```
#include <stdexcept>
int Mystack::pop()
{
    if (isEmpty())
       throw std::out_of_range("Stack Underflow");
    std::cout << "The popped element is" << A[top];
    return A[top--];
}
```

On the client side:

```
void foo() 
{
   Mystack ms;
   //...
  try 
  {
    ms.pop();
  }
  catch (const std::out_of_range& oor) 
  {
    std::cerr << "Out of Range error: " << oor.what() << '\n';
  }
}
```

Edit:  As the comments below mentioned, you can also derive your own exception from `std::exception`.  Here is a simple example:

```
#include <stdexcept>
struct myStackException : public std::exception
{
   const char *what() const noexcept { return "Stack Overflow"; }
};

int Mystack::pop()
{
    if (isEmpty())
        throw myStackException();
    std::cout << "The popped element is" << A[top];
    return A[top--];
}
```

Live (dummy) example: http://ideone.com/ZyqiQ0

Comment: [`std::out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) is in `<stdexcept>` header.

Comment: regarding `out_of_range`, its advantage is that it sounds conforming. disadvantages include (1) [sorry, deleted], and (2) that it will fly right through code that only catches `runtime_error`. in addition to these considerations, i think it should be mentioned that this design of `pop` is not exception safe for other stack item types (in general).

Answer (score 1):

Re

> **”**  What improvement overall can be made to this `pop` function

You can

- Make it `void` to make it more **exception safe** for other item types.
  *With the current design, if copying of the popped item fails, then there is no way to recover.*
- Remove internal output.
- `assert` that the underflow doesn't occur, so that this can be caught in testing.

Thus,

```
void Mystack::pop()
{
    assert( top > 0 );
    --top;
}
```

Wow, what a simplification – and now more exception safe too!

As an alternative to the `assert` you can throw an exception. That's better than the original, but absolutely not better than the `assert`. It moves correctness issues into the runtime domain, to be handled and perhaps worked around by each caller site.

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of using C++ exceptions is that error handling code can be separated from user code, alleviating the need for code to be littered with error handling code that is common in C programs. Throwing an exception also offers a solution to returning a invalid value in the error case

```
if( s1.pop() == 0 ){
    // is this an error or not?
}
```

Exceptions can be added to your code like so, by taking advantage in the generic exceptions in the

```
#include <stdexcept>
```

header file.

```
int Mystack::pop()
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        throw std::range_error("nothing to pop");
    }
    std::cout << "The popped element is" << A[top];
    return A[top--];
}
```

Then you add a try/catch block to the appropriate code, perhaps with

```
case 4:
        std::cout << "POP the element" << std::endl;
        try{
            s1.pop();
        }
        catch(const std::range_error& e)
        {
            std::cerr << "unable to pop!\n";
            // error handling code
        }
        break;
```

Another solution, particularly appropriate when errors aren't as exceptional, such as with file I/O is more intrusive to the user code, but offers a better solution than returning an arbitrary value

```
int Mystack::pop(int& value)
{
    if( isEmpty() )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "The popped element is" << A[top];
    value = A[top--];
    return 0
}
```

And then your code becomes

```
case 4:
    std::cout << "POP the element" << std::endl;
    {
        int value;
        if( s1.pop(value) == 1 ){
            // error code
        }
    }
        break;
```